# Context data does not get passed into nested component: React+Typescript+ContextAPI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am using context **API** to avoid prop drilling across the components. I have a component which has two popup modal's(components). When I am trying to fetch the context data within Enclosing component data, but within the modal I would not get. If I pass again pass this context data as a props to these modal's and then if I fetch this props accessor then I am able to fetch. Where am I going wrong? If I am not wrong, this context **API** does not depend on the nested levels, can someone help me here?

**CacheContext.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
const context = React.createContext(null);
export default context;
```

**ContextProvider.tsx**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

import context from './CacheContext';

var TinyCache = require( 'tinycache' );
var cache = new TinyCache();

class ContextProvider extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
          <context.Provider value={cache}>
               {this.props.children}
          </context.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  export default ContextProvider;
```

### ComponentA.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import context from "../Utilities/CacheContext";

export default class ComponentA extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context) // I am able to the data here
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <Modal1/>   //if I pass this as context={this.context} then it works
        <Modal2/>
    )
  }
}
ComponentA.contextType=context;
```

### Modal1.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import context from "../Utilities/CacheContext";

export default class Modal1 extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

   componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context) // I am unable able to the data here , If I use this.props.context and pass the context as props then I am able to get
  }

  render(){
    return(
        //some content
    )
  }
}
Modal1.contextType=context;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new context API ( https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api ) You should use the context.Consumer component using a function as children:

```
<context.Consumer>
  {cache => console.log(cache)}
</context.Consumer>
```

If you need the cache in componentDidMount, pass the cache to a sub-component like this:

```
// render:
<context.Consumer>
  {cache => <SubComponent cache={cache}/>}
</context.Consumer>

// SubComponent:
class SubComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.cache);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mihalyi, I want to use it outside the render method

Comment: Subcomponents cannot access this without having to pass them as props?

Comment: I think, it is not possible